# Function Timeout Issue when using app service plan

Tags: azure-function-app

I have set up azure function app in app service plan. The azure function is made of of durable function with multiple activity triggers. When the data is huge, the last activity trigger times out with 404 gateway timeout error, but when I check the called method, it is still getting executing.
I read that app service plan has infinite timeout, even after that I added the functiontimeout setting in host.json.
Still no help. And the process keeps failing with gateway timeout error.

Comment: Can you confirm if you are getting 404 or 502 error ?

Comment: 504 Gateway timeout error